# Is it possible to combine two hash functions in such a way that cracking the constructed hash would require cracking the constituent hashes?

Tags: hash

Suppose **A** is some arbitrary hash function, for example *BCrypt* or *MD5*. And **B** be some other arbitrary hash function, maybe *SHA256* or *SCrypt*.

Let `passwordHashedWithA = A(password)` and  `passwordHashedWithB = B(password)`.

If an attacker is given *just* `passwordHashedWithA` and finds a `pA` such that:

`passwordHashedWithA == A(pA)`

Then the attacker has performed a successful *preimage* attack on **A**.

I want to know if it is theoretically possible to construct a hash function **C** out of two arbitrary hash functions **A** and **B**, such that for *any* **A** and **B**, performing a successful preimage attack on **C** would *require* performing a preimage attack on **both A and B**. The question can be extended to build **C** from *N* arbitrary hash functions.

I strongly suspect that this is theoretically impossible; it seems like a free lunch. But I cannot begin to think how to prove it.

If such a thing does exist then it would be incredibly useful: we could combine old, proven hashes like BCrypt with slightly newer and fancier hashes like SCrypt, such that we have the best of both worlds. Like I said - sounds too much like a free lunch.

I am asking this from a theoretical perspective, I'm aware that `BCrypt` or `SCrypt` are probably *good enough* for most production systems.

I'm looking for a proof that this is impossible, or a construction of **C** that provides these properties.

### Examples of C that don't work

Suppose we try `C(password) = A(password) + B(password)` where + is just concatenation of the hashes.

The result of this is obviously a weaker hash: we can preimage **C** by finding the original password by cracking  **A** *or* **B**.

If we try `C(password) = A(B(password))`, this initially looks stronger but you really can't say much about **C** without looking at the specifics of **A** and **B**. For example if **A** was a completely useless hash that always returned a constant string, the strengths in **B** would be irrelevant, and any string would be a preimage of **C**.

Comment: What about `C(password) = A(B(password) || password)` where || is concatenation? I don't have time to prove it now but it appears to work around the issue you found with just composing the two hash functions.

Comment: Is'nt the answer you want exactly the top answer to this question http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/270/guarding-against-cryptanalytic-breakthroughs-combining-multiple-hash-functions ?

Comment: Thank you! Yes I hadn't seen that question - it is remarkably similar. Unfortunately the answers do not focus on preimage attacks and are not written in a formal manor. This question specifically asks for those things but does that constitute a significant enough difference?

Comment: @Thomas if `A` gave constant output then all of B's strengths would be lost in `C`

Comment: @Thomas : ​ `A` might leak a significant portion of its input. ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 3):

> Suppose we try `C(password) = A(password) + B(password)` where + is just concatenation of the hashes.
>
> The result of this is obviously a weaker hash: we can preimage **C** by finding the original password by cracking  **A** *or* **B**.

This is incorrect with the standard notion of preimage resistance.

Because there are many more possible inputs to a hash function than outputs, there are necessarily collisions. Even if $A$ allows you to find *a* preimage, that is not necessarily a preimage for $B$. For random inputs and unrelated hashes, it very likely is not.

In practical applications this is quite a bit more messy. For example, if you take $A$ to be the truncate function (to e.g. 256 bits, zero-padded), it lets you find a preimage for the concatenated hash *if* the input is short enough. For the vast majority of possible inputs it does not directly give you a preimage, but that is cold comfort if hashing e.g. typical passwords.

---

If you want a provably robust combiner, you could look into the thesis linked [from an answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/328/13625) to the previous question: [Anja Lehmann: "On the security of hash function combiners"](http://tuprints.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/2094/1/thesis.lehmann.pdf) (pdf). It offers good combiners that are unfortunately rather complex.

For a simpler combiner, you could use XOR like TLS does. You do not get a nice proof from only the *preimage resistance* of the hash, but it is provably PRF if either of the two password hashes is PRF (and they are independent). That is a practical choice that is probably good enough if you take care to use different hashes.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful - however I carefully worded my statement "we can preimage C by finding the original password by cracking A or B." which I believe is correct - if we find the *original password* by cracking A or B, then we have found a preimage of C. I did not say preimaging A or B was equivalent to preimaging C, finding the original input however would be.

Comment: @GeorgePowell, yes, I addressed that in the third paragraph. However, in practice it seems rather unlikely that a password hash would have a preimage attack that allowed one to find that particular preimage quickly.