# Robust combiner for preimage resistance

Tags: hash, protocol-design, preimage-resistance

My question is about chaining two hash functions to create a robust combiner
for preimage resistance. @Zooko already gave a detailed answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/328/57619):

> $$H_{\circ}(x) = H_0(H_1(x))$$
>
> is as strong as the strongest of its two components.

However, in the comments below, @Arno Mittelbach showed the idea was dangerous: if $H_0$ is a random oracle and $H_1$ is a constant function (that maps every input to $0$), $H_{\circ}(x)$ is a constant function. However, he did not address @Paŭlo Ebermann's construction

> $$H_{\circ}(x) = H_0(H_1(x)|x)$$
>
> ...to have the improved preimage resistance, while still not having more collisions than with only one hash.

when $H_1$ is constant function, @Paŭlo Ebermann's construction

$$H_{\circ}(x) = H_0(H_1(x)|x) = H_0(0|x)$$

appears to be indifferentiable from a random oracle. However, I understand it might be impossible to know which function is the constant function. If it's $H_0$,

$$H_{\circ}(x) = H_0(H_1(x)|x) = 0$$

So I'm wondering if this knowledge gap can be remedied by using construction

$$H_{\circ}(x) = H_0(H_1(x)|x) \oplus H_1(H_0(x)|x)$$

In that case if $H_1$ is a constant function

$$H_{\circ}(x) = H_0(0|x) \oplus 0 = H_0(0|x)$$

On the other hand, if $H_0$ is a constant function

$$H_{\circ}(x) = 0 \oplus H_1(0|x) = H_1(0|x)$$

Is there any downsides to this construction outside speed? I understand it does not distribute trust on collision resistance, that is okay considering my use case.

Also, I'm unsure if [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/070.pdf) paper applies to my construction as one of my hash functions is Blake2 and another is SHA3-256 (which is wide-pipe sponge function, not MD/HAIFA). To my knowledge it was also the case none of the attacked constructions in the paper were against constructions that contained chained hash functions.

Comment: [This paper may also be interesting to you.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/723)

Answer (score 2):

In your construction, if $H_0 = H_1$ (same function), then your $H_{\circ}$ is constant and equal to $0$. More generally, that kind of construction relies on the two underlying hash functions to be "different" from each other in a way which is very hard to define properly, let alone achieve. If $H_0$ and $H_1$ are *independent random oracles*, then most constructions are fine; but, there again, random oracles [don't really exist](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/880/28).

Comment: You're right, one has to be careful not to use same the hash function. In my case $H_0$ is BLAKE2b with digest length of 32 bytes and $H_1$ is SHA3-256. My understanding of the algorithms isn't very deep but from what I've read, NIST chose Keccak because it was different from SHA2. BLAKE2 authors, on the other hand, [argue](https://leastauthority.com/blog/BLAKE2-harder-better-faster-stronger-than-MD5/) the strength of their algorithm is it's similarity with the well studied SHA2.